# Process jQuery/Sizzle queries on string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I have a string from a server that I need to modify before adding it to the DOM. I would like to replace  `<div data-role="placeholder" />` which come in a lot of formats (new line, etc) and extra attributes.

Here's an example of my string:

```
 <span title="15 gold badges"><div data-role="placeholder" /></span>
 <span title="25 starts"><div data-role="placeholder" id="test"></div></span>
```

How can I query for placeholders and replace it with another HTML string such as `<div data-role="calendar" />`?

Comment: Could you show a full example of the string? Did you already try putting it in a jQuery object and just search for the div?

Comment: I added a string example of HTML, but this is a string and not part of the DOM.

Comment: Also, that div should be a self closing element you should check your server response and correct that. If you are using string replace it might cause problems in some browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways of doing this. You either use the good old `.replace()` or you wrap it in a jQuery object and use the DOM manipulation methods.

**Use string replace**

```js
var html = '<span title="15 gold badges">' +
  '<div data-role="placeholder" />' +
  '</span><span title="25 starts">' +
  '<div data-role="placeholder" id="test">' +
  '</div></span>';


$('body').append(html.replace(/data-role="placeholder"/g, 'data-role="calendar"'));


$('div[data-role=calendar]').text('yay!');
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Use jQuery methods**

```js
var html = '<span title="15 gold badges">' +
  '<div data-role="placeholder" />' +
  '</span><span title="25 starts">' +
  '<div data-role="placeholder" id="test">' +
  '</div></span>';


$(html).find('[data-role]').attr('data-role', 'calendar').end().appendTo('body');


$('div[data-role=calendar]').text('yay!');
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```